# Delete multiple rows to replace with one row

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table `foo` like below where `datetime` and `location` together make the primary index.

| datetime | location | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| date1 | loc1 | 0 |
| date1 | loc2 | 0 |
| date1 | loc3 | 0 |
| date1 | ... | 0 |
| date1 | loc999 | 0 |
| date2 | loc1 | 0.01 |
| date2 | loc2 | 0.02 |
| date2 | loc3 | 0 |
| date2 | ... | 0 |
| date2 | loc999 | 0 |

There are cases when all values for a specific `datetime` are `0` (`date1` in the example above). In this case, I want to delete all such rows and replace them with a single row. In the new row, `datetime` -> `date1`, `location` -> `EVERYWHERE`, and `value` -> `0`. I know how to select and delete the rows, but how can I replace multiple rows at once?

Comment: please do provide table names when you ask questions; that makes it easier to answer and to understand or compare answers

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary table to store the datetime values for the rows you are replacing:

```
create table foo (datetime text, location text, value decimal(20,2));

insert into foo values
('date1','loc1',0),
('date1','loc2',0),
('date1','loc3',0),
('date1','loc99',0),
('date2','loc1',0.02),
('date2','loc2',0),
('date2','loc3',0),
('date2','loc99',0);

create temporary table foo_all_zero (datetime text)
select datetime
from foo
group by datetime
having sum(not(value<=>0))=0;

delete foo from foo join foo_all_zero using (datetime);

insert into foo (datetime,location,value)
select datetime,'EVERYWHERE',0
from foo_all_zero
```

`sum(not(value<=>0))` counts rows for the datetime where the value is not 0 (including detecting null).  If the column is `not null`, it can just use `having sum(value<>0)=0`